# How to wire multiple 12w pot lights w/boxes & wall switches onto a single 20 amp circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, repair, circuit-breaker

Hello I have a RV using a 30 amp distribution panel/system.

I want to install 5 120V prepackaged pot lights with receptacle boxes. and wire in 5 light switches.

I am a novice electrician and I'm not sure how to wire the pot light and the receptacle box and the light switch of 5 pot lights onto one line leading back to the 20 amp circuit breaker. I'm using 12/2 wire. And I'm not sure if I need a  Square D HOM dual or single 20 amp breaker for this endeavor. I'm just feeling a little lost.

Thank you very much and any advice would be greatly appreciated! I have multiple pictures on my Facebook account of my project. thank you and have a great day

Comment: Can you upload those pictures by [edit]ing your post, then using the "mountain and sun" button in the post editor?

Comment: Nobody here is going to spend hours trying to find _your_ Facebook account. Some people here _gasp!_ don't even have Facebook accounts and don't want 'em.

Comment: A 30amp RV system is 120v so you would never need a double pole.. the wattage is low so no issues there . I would also want led so you can also power them on generator without problems. RV’s have thin walls and there special in wall splices for Romex that may help you out.

Comment: what good are pictures on your facebook account? ... what is the point of even mentioning then?